# openlayers 4 cannot add vector source

Tags: openlayers, vector-layer, typescript

I'm trying to add a vector layer from vector source , but getting error like this

```
AppComponent.html:1 ERROR TypeError: this.adaptAttributions_ is not a function
    at Object._ol_source_Source_ (source.js:41)
```

here is my code ,

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

import OlMap from 'ol/map';
import OlXYZ from 'ol/source/xyz';
import OlTileLayer from 'ol/layer/tile';
import OlView from 'ol/view';
import OlProj from 'ol/proj';
import OlProjection from 'ol/proj/projection'
import OlExtent from 'ol/extent';
import OlTileGrid from 'ol/tilegrid/tilegrid'
import OlLayer from 'ol/layer/layer';
import OlLayerImage from 'ol/layer/image';
import OlSource from 'ol/source/source';
import OlSourceOSM from 'ol/source/osm';
import OlTileWMS from 'ol/source/tilewms';
import OlVector from 'ol/source/vector';
import OlLayerVector from 'ol/layer/vector';
import OlFormatGeoJSON from 'ol/format/geojson';
import OlLoadingStrategy from 'ol/loadingstrategy';
import OlImageWMS from 'ol/source/imagewms';
import OlStyle from 'ol/style'
import Proj4 from 'proj4';
//import * as ol from 'ol';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']
})

export class MapComponent implements OnInit {

  map: OlMap;
  source: OlXYZ;
  layer: OlTileLayer;
  view: OlView;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

      var vectorSource = OlVector({
        format: new OlFormatGeoJSON(),
        url: function(extent) {
    return 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/workspace/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=workspace:roadcentreline&outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:32640&'+
    'bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:32640';

        },
        strategy: OlLoadingStrategy.bbox
      });

      Proj4.defs("EPSG:32640","+proj=utm +zone=40 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs");
      var proj27700 = OlProjection.get('EPSG:32640');


       var vector = new OlLayerVector({
        source: vectorSource,
        style: new OlStyle.Style({
          stroke: new OlStyle.Stroke({
            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1.0)',
            width: 2
          })
        })
      });

      this.view= new OlView({
                    center: [376581.6867, 2679756.7678],
                    projection: 'EPSG:32640',
                    maxZoom: 19,
                    zoom: 15
        });

        this.map= new OlMap({
        layers: [vector],
        target: document.getElementById('map'),
        view: this.view
      });


  }
}
```

i used same version of openlayers(4.6.5) used [here](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-wfs.html?q=vector%20source)

working here, but not for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "new" keyword for OlVector.

```
 var vectorSource = new OlVector({
        format: new OlFormatGeoJSON(),
        url: function(extent) {
    return 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/workspace/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=workspace:roadcentreline&outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:32640&'+
    'bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:32640';

        },
        strategy: OlLoadingStrategy.bbox
      });
```